# getting "void value not ignored as it ought to be" in C

Tags: c

I started learning C in class and have started the assignment but I'm writing it one piece at a time. Currently I'm stuck because I may be doing something completely wrong but I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: `deck[i] = displayCard(i)` .. but if you get **void**, how can you assign (nothing) to `deck[i]`?

Comment: Read the task again. 1) create the array of cards [where each card is represented by a value from `[0..SIZE)`]; 2) deal [the first?] card from the deck; 3) display *a [that?] card*; 4) shuffle the deck. It never said to assign the **void** (nothing) result of `displayCard`, but only suggested that it could be used for *part/one* of the the tasks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your `for` loop in `main`, `deck[i] = i;` is all you need.  Then you can display any card in the deck by doing `displayCard(deck[j]);` for `0 < j < 52`.  Then, your shuffling function should change values of `deck[i]` so that `deck[i] == i` is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear... The void type isn't something you can return / store in a variable. Instead it's a special type that means "nothing". You can't store nothing, you must ignore the return or return something.

Answer (score 0):

displayCard only displays the cards, it does nothing to define them, so you shouldn't be trying to use it to create your cards. Instead, think about what a "card" actually is in your program--what, for example, do you have to pass to displayCard in order for it to know which card to display?